# Count in upload files in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, postman

I can't understand why this happen;

I select 3 files in postman and _POST it.

But it always return 5.

I think count($_FILES['filename']) return files count number but it is not.

So I check the file size and count it, same return, 5.

This is my codeigniter code, it is simple.

If you know about it, please help me

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to send the key from postman with array, `Image[]` ?

Comment: Post code not image of code

Comment: @Marprin  Yes this is my mistake I don't post it with array

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I miss it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Polaris,

It will always return 5 because the Image element that you are posting from PostMan isn't a array.

Second thing is when you post a file to a script it always have

```
$_FILES['Image'] => array(
    [name] => '',
    [type] => '',
    [tmp_name] => '',
    [error] => '',
    [size] =>''
);
```

So use the Image name as Image[] , make sure you have square backets"[]" after the Image key name.

Right now everytime you write
    count($_FILES['Image']);
It will return 5. Use [] in the key name

Comment: Thanks you save my time:)